# passing Arabic parameter in sql server stored

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
create proc [dbo].[My_Test] --1,'السادس',1
(
@Grade nvarchar(50)

)
as

begin
declare @s  nvarchar(50) 
set @s= N''+  @Grade  +''
print @s
```

the result is ?????????

how to make it working well?

Comment: Are you using ntext or nvarchar for your columns data type.  The reason you want to use nvarchar is when you have different languages in the same column, as it appears you are using english and arabic, you need to address the columns in T-SQL without decoding, you want to be able to see the data "natively" in SSMS, or you want to standardize on Unicode.

Comment: i have already know that idea , but what about c# code , how can i prefix N before the parameter passing in the code to data base???

Comment: my problem is when i put the parameter 'السادس' from C# code , it retrieves nothing , although when i put it as N'السادس' in Sql , it retrieves data

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix Unicode strings with the N prefix. Compare:

```
SELECT 'السادس', N'السادس';
```

Results:

```
------    --------
??????    السادس
```

Try executing your stored procedure by properly prefixing your string with `N` (and name your parameters too) e.g.:

```
EXEC dbo.My_Test @Grade = N'السادس';
```

Also instead of this:

```
declare @s  nvarchar(50) 
set @s= N''+  @Grade  +''
print @s
```

Just do this:

```
PRINT @Grade;
```

The second variable, the declare, set etc. all seem like extra noise for nothing... you don't need to wrap it in quotes and add the `N` prefix at that point. Only necessary when you are specifying a string literal.

Comment: i know that i should prefix my parameter with N , but i call this execution from c# page , So, i want to know how to prefix my parameter with N in my C# page? thanks

Comment: @user3261588 well, you'll need to show your C# code in order to help determine why this value isn't being passed correctly from your C# code. I only answered because in the T-SQL code sample above you are clearly not properly prefixing the string literal with `N`.

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         cmd_Material.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd_Material.CommandText = "My-Test";
        SqlParameter prm_Grade = new SqlParameter("@Grade", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        prm_Grade.Value = Grade;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm_Grade);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
        return dt_Material;

Comment: @user3261588 Wow. Please put the C# code in your question; absolutely unreadable in a comment. Anyway, from a quick glance it looks like this should be ok, how are you verifying that the data isn't correct? Where are you observing the `PRINT` output?

Comment: my problem is when i put the parameter 'السادس' from C# code , it retrieves nothing , although when i put it as N'السادس' in Sql , it retrieves data